# Why are there primitive functions like DoubleFunction in Java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming

I just had a look at the the new Java 8 [function package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) and wonder why there are interfaces like

- `DoubleFunction`
- `IntFunction`
- `LongFunction`
- ...

which do **not** extend `Function`. Doesn't that mean I will not be able to pass a `Function<T,Int>` where a `IntFunction<T>` is required and vice versa? The same applies for `*Block`, `*Supplier` and `*UnaryOperator`.

I can see the advantage that I will not have to check for `null` when a primitive is returned, but the list of disadvantages seem to be much longer

Comment: Related to (but *not* a direct duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/q/23007422/2886891

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is related to the fact that primitive types in Java are not unified to be substitutable for `Object`, and with generic type erasure.

Using `Function<T, Integer>` instead of `IntFunction<T>` when the last one suffices has 2 disadvantages:

- Every returned `int` is boxed - meaning a larger memory footprint;
- Every returned `Integer` gets an automatic runtime check (which can be optimized away, but yeah...);

Note that these kinds of issues with the collection framework in Java have led people to write a whole library, named Trove, that eschews the generic interfaces in favor of specialized collection types for every primitive type.

Comment: This seems to trade the possiblity of higher programming abstractions and cleaner code for premature optimization

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt: Oh, absolutely, and it's super depressing.