# Using Streams with primitives data types and corresponding wrappers

Tags: java, wrapper, java-8, primitive-types, java-stream

While playing around with Java8's Streams-API, I stumbled over the following:

To convert an array of primitive wrapper classe objects into a `Stream` I just have to call `Stream.of(array)`. But to convert an array of primitive data types, I have to call `.of(array)` from the corresponding wrapper (class) stream class (<-- that sounds silly).

An example:

```
final Integer[] integers = {1, 2, 3};
final int[]     ints     = {1, 2, 3};


Stream.of(integers).forEach(System.out::println); //That works just fine

Stream.of(ints).forEach(System.out::println);     //That doesn't

IntStream.of(ints).forEach(System.out::println);  //Have to use IntStream instead
```

**My question(s):**
Why is this? Does this correlate to e.g. the behaviour of `Arrays.asList()` which also just works for wrapper class arrays?

Comment: Isn't it normal to use IntStream methods to deal with IntStreams, and Stream methods to deal with Streams?

Comment: You can also use `Arrays.stream(ints).forEach(System.out::println)`.

Comment: Related to (but not a direct duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/q/14850879/2886891

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Java 8 stream framework has a generic `Stream<T>` for objects as elements, and three primitive streams `IntStream`, `LongStream`, `DoubleStream` for the main three primitives. If you work with primitives, use one of those latter, in your case `IntStream`.

See the picture:

[image]

What lies behind is that:

1. [Java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) cannot work with primitive types: it is possible to have only `List<Integer>` and `Stream<Integer>`, but not <s>`List<int>`</s> and <s>`Stream<int>`</s>
2. When the [Java Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) framework was introduced, it was introduced only for classes, so if you want to have a `List` of `int`s, you have to wrap them (each single element!) to `Integer`s. This is costly!
3. When the [Java Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) framework was introduced, they decided to get around this overhead and *in parallel* with the "class-oriented" streams (using the generics mechanism), they introduced three extra sets of all the library functions, specifically designed for the most important primitive types: `int`, `long`, `double`.

BTW, they did the same with the predefined functional interfaces in the [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package, so you have `Predicate`, `IntPredicate`, `DoublePredicate`, and `LongPredicate`.

And see also a marvelous explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22919112/2886891