# Why java.util.function doesn't define specialized functional interfaces for all primitive types?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

Java 8 provides several functional interfaces in package [`java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

For each basic function (Function, Consumer, Predicate, Supplier...) there are other defined where the type parameter is specialized for the following primitive type: double, int, long.

This questions is about the motivation of such interfaces: [Why are there primitive functions like DoubleFunction in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850879/why-are-there-primitive-functions-like-doublefunction-in-java-8)

But why not all the primitive types are covered (e.g. float is missing)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was decided in order to prevent API size explosion. Being forced to introduce primitive specializations at all is already a pain point, so the compromise was to specialize only for the essential types, which are `long` and `double`, and additionally for `int` as the most prominent primitive type: the type of array indices and  integer literals. All other types can be promoted to these.

In [this post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006750.html) on the *lambda-dev* mailing list you can read the official statement from Brian Goetz.